Is saying "Both A and not-A can do B" contradictory?
Take this example:
(1) Both blondes and non-blondes can do logic. (Premiss)
(2) If someone is blonde, then they can do logic (Derived from 1)
(3) If someone is not blonde, then they can do logic (Derived from 1)
(4) If someone cannot do logic, then they are not blonde (Contrapositive of 2)
Now statements (3) and (4) are contradictory, and they derive from (1), so (1) must be wrong, but it is the case that (1) is true in reality.
So what am I missing?

3 and 4 are not contradictory. Considering that 1 says that everybody can do logic, if someone cannot do it then they do not exist, making 3 and 4 both true.

Not an exact dupe, but I think vacuously true is what you're looking for. "All people who can't do logic can do logic, are blond, and have wings" is true because there are no such people.

@Conifold I think OP is interpreting existential import in the universal statements. Of course, this needs to be specified, but I think that’s what’s going on.

Depending on how you define non-blondes and someones (can a rock be a non-blonde? If so, can it be a someone?), the phrase someone cannot do logic may be a contradiction in itself.

If so, 4 is true, but so is "if someone cannot do logic, I am a pineapple"

If rocks can be non-blonde someone's, then there's no problem at all.

Related? or not really? Can deer be at the zoo if there are deer at the zoo, and some deer have antlers?

Improperly closed and all of the answers are semantic. Let our domain be a person, B be blondeness, and L be logic ability. We are given (1) B | ~B → L and have the law of contraposition, so we also have excluded middle, meaning B | ~B is a theorem and so is L. Thus (4) is an absurdity since it starts from ~L. No semantic interpretation required!

First of all the premise might be somewhat ambiguous as to how vast the groups that are mentioned actually are.
Like does "Both blondes and non-blondes can do logic." mean that ALL blondes and ALL non-blondes can do logic or that SOME blondes and SOME non-blondes can? Like this could both imply that being blonde or non-blonde is not excluding you per se from the group that is capable of doing logic, while the other implies that you can see a person's logical skill by their hair color.
Also using a thing and it's opposite implies that the list is conclusive but for example would a bald person count as blonde or non-blonde or would they be their own category. So are we in binary territory or does your logic have more than 2 possible states?
Like the way you construct your argument it seems as if you assume it's ALL and it's binary, but that's not necessarily self-evident from the premise.
Also 3) and 4) are not in contradiction. Like if every blond person can do logic than a person who can't do logic can't be blonde because every blonde person apparently can do logic. So 4 fits. And if also every non-blonde person can do logic, than a person not being able to do logic also can't be non-blonde. So as a consequence that could also mean that there are no people who can't do logic or that people who can't do logic neither fall into the category of blonde or non-blonde. In both cases the statements would be non-contradicting.

"statements (3) and (4) are contradictory, "
These are not contradictory:

(3) If someone is not blonde, then they can do logic
(4) If someone cannot do logic, then they are not blonde

Because the set referred to in (4) is always null (per 1 and 2).
Assuming no unicorns exist, all of these statements are true and noncontradictory:
All unicorns are blue
No unicorns are blue
All unicorns are not blue
If you brought Nietzsche into your country, he'd be an existential import.

Is saying "Both A and not-A can do B" contradictory?
No. Your example illustrates the fallacy, denying the antecedent.
The example says that

If Event A, then Event B AND if Event not-A, then Event B.

In practical terms, the example is saying that Event B is going to happen no matter what. Event A might occur, or it might not, but in any case, Event B will.
Now suppose the example said:

If Event A, then Event B AND if Event A, then Event not- B.>

Then the contradiction problem would appear.

"Then the contradiction problem would appear." You can arrive at this situation by deriving "can't do logic -> is blonde" from 3 (which is its contrapositive). There's no contradiction here however, because "can't do logic" is always false.

The contraposition in statement (4) states that, if somebody cannot do logic, they cannot be blonde. But this doesn't mean that they could have another hair color. The problem is that the class that cannot do logic is excluded by statement (1), making the contraposition meaningless.
If we stated that:
(1) blonde humans and non-blonde humans can do logic, but animals can't do logic.
Then the contraposition would mean that those who cannnot do logic cannot be blonde humans, because they cannot be humans at all. In terms of the Venn diagram (borrowed from Wikipedia): A represents blonde humans, B represents all humans (blonde and non-blonde), while the outside of the diagram represents those who cannot do logic.


I don't think they are contradictory, because essentially you're saying that both whatever is A and whatever is not A can do B.
If your entire population is just A and B then both A and B (not A) can do B.
What might be confusing is that B can do whatever B is.
Deriving from your logic I'd rather frame it as A (blondes) can do C (logic) and not A (B or not blondes) can do C as well.
The issue in your statement is that you define blondes as A, logic as B but don't define what is not A, technically speaking if you only have A and B, you'd be saying blondes can do logic and whatever is not blonde (in this case logic) can do logic as well, and here is where it gets confusing as I said before, because you'd be saying logic can do logic.
